# Setting up a Set Password (similar to Reset Password) in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When a user is logged on, I've added the ability for that user to create a new user (specifying an email address, without providing a password).

When that's done, I want the new user to get an email (like the Reset Password email with a link) that will send the user to a *Set Password* page (similar to the Reset Password view).

I figured out how to send the New user a regular email in the store function (UserController) :

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create(Request::all());

    Mail::send('users.welcomemail', [], function ($message) { 
        $message->from('email@example.com', 'Email');
        $message->to('email@example.com', 'Email')->subject('Welcome!');
    });

    return redirect('business/');
}
```

I've create a new view for *Setting a Password* (copied from views/auth/reset.blade.php).

I'm just not sure what I should write (for *Setting up a password*) to my controller so it acts like the *Reset a password* function. Any ideas would help.

If possible, I would like to use what exists already in laravel.. default user table and controller, and password_resets table.

**update - solution**

I've managed to make it work.

UsersController

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create(Request::all());

    $contactfirstname = $user->first_name;
    $contactemail = $user->email;

    $token = hash_hmac('sha256', str_random(40), config('app.key'));

    DB::table('password_resets')->insert(['email' => $user->email, 'token' => $token, 'created_at' =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()]);

    Mail::send('users.welcomemail', ['user' => $user, 'token' => $token], function ($message) use ($contactfirstname, $contactemail)
    { 
        $message->from('name@email.com', 'My name');
        $message->to($contactemail, $contactfirstname)->subject('Welcome!');
    });

    return redirect('business/');
}
```

users.welcomemail view

```
<h1>Hi! {{ $user->first_name }}</h1>

<p>We'd like to personally welcome you. Thank you for registering!</p>

<p>Please click the link below to set your account password and get access to your account :</p>

<p><a href="{{ URL::to('auth/passwordset/' .  $token) }}">{{ URL::to('auth/passwordset/' .  $token) }}</a></p>
```

route

```
('/auth/passwordset/{token}', 'PasswordSetupController@passwordset');
```

passwordSetupController

```
class PasswordsetController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Passwordset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles password setups for new users
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function passwordset($token)
    {
        return view('users.passwordset')->with(['token' => $token]);
    }
}
```

passwordset/{token} view

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Set Password</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Set Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are creating the new account using the new email address, you also need to put a unique value in the database for that email, for example, you may create a record in the database using `email` and `token` fields so when creating the record and storing the `email` also store the token (unique). To get a unique token you may try this:

```
$token = hash_hmac('sha256', str_random(40), config('app.key'));
```

Now save the record in the database and send the email with a link and the link could be look something like this:

```
http://example.com/set/password/the-token-you-created-for-this-user
```

Now, just create a route for the link, for example:

```
get('/set/password/{token}', 'PasswordSetupController@getSetPassword');
```

Now, in the controller, declare the method, for example:

```
public function getSetPassword($token)
{
    // find the token from the database
    // if you can find a record, for example:
    $model = SomeModel::whereToken($token)->first();

    if($model) {
        // The matching $token is found. So show a view to set the password
        // with a form textbox and submit button, set form action, add route
        // for that action. Also, add a hidden field in the form for token,
        // so you can check it again on form submission
    }
}
```

Create a method for form processing, for example:

```
public function postSetPassword()
{
    if($token = Input::get('hidden_token_field')) {
        // Match it again and if matches then save the password and delete
        // the hashed record or update the hashed field, just figure it out.
    }
}
```

Route could be:

```
post('/set/password', 'PasswordSetupController@postSetPassword');
```

This is an abstract idea but you should be able to do the required work. I gave you the idea you asked for. Hope it'll help you. Make sure to set the form method `POST` according to the route above.

Comment: Thanks @TheAlpha. I'm using the user table and controller that comes with Laravel, i'm not sure though where to save that token (is it the remember_token column in the User table)? I noticed that Laravel created a password_resets table, should I play with that?

Comment: Yes, you can play with that or you can create your own but you can follow that table that Laravel uses for password reset.

Comment: After i've generated the $token, what would be the syntax to add it to the password_resets table from my user controller?

Comment: You may try `DB::table('password_reset')->->insert(['email' => '...', 'token' => '...']);`

Comment: I'm almost there. The user gets his email with set password link. I add the new row with token in password_resets when the user is created. When the new user clicks the link, he's presented with the exact same view as the reset password view (except it's written Set Password). From there, I thought that submitting the form (it goes to the same url of RESET) would automatically delete the row in password_resets, and update the users password.. but it doesn't haha. I don't know would LAravel handles this, but it "knows" i'm not doing a REAL reset

Comment: Actually, Laravel would do that if you submit the form to that URL and use an email field as well, otherwise you have to process the submission.

Comment: I've updated the code in my question. The form the user gets to Set his password was copied directly from the Reset password view. It posts to: `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">` so I thought it would work, but doesn't seem like it.

Comment: It worked! Did a `php artisan migrate:refresh` and everything is working now. Thanks for your help @TheAlpha